# ¿Como pasar filas a columnas en R?

Tags: r, rstudio, dataframe

Hola Comunidad quería preguntares si es posible dejar el usuario con id 10 en una sola fila dejando como identificador la variable id y las demás variables pasarlas a columnas usando R. Gracias [image: Dataframe de ejemplo]

Comment: Has intentado algo?

Comment: Si Cesar, he intentado con Reshape.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

#### Con `dplyr/tidyverse`

Puedes usar el verbo `pivot_wider()` para pasar variables distribuidas en filas a columnas:

```
library("tidyverse")  

nombres <- names(df)[-c(1,2)]
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = fyhingresopte, 
              values_from=matches(nombres))
```

#### con R base

Puedes usar `rehape()`:

```
reshape(df, timevar = "fyhingresopte", idvar = "record_id", direction = "wide")
```

#### Reducir número de columnas

Como has observado cada columna es una versión de la misma por cada una de las fechas, si no quieres esto, puedes enumerar las fechas de cada grupo y usar este dato:

```
df %>%
  group_by(record_id) %>% 
  arrange(fyhingresopte) %>% 
  mutate(ncol=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ncol, 
              values_from=-record_id)
```

#### Ejemplo de datos:

```
df <- read.table(text = '"record_id" "fyhingresopte" "pruebacovid" "resultadopcr" "viaje14d" "personalsalud" "contacto14d" "ingresourgencias" "otrainstitucion" "observacionesingresourg"
1 "2020-03-20 23:58" 1 1 2 2 1 2 "" "NINGUNA"
1 "" NA NA NA NA NA NA "" ""
2 "2020-03-29 09:46" 1 1 2 2 2 1 "" "Llevado por su madre"
10 "2020-03-13 22:41" 1 2 1 2 2 1 "" ""
10 "2020-03-16 01:10" 2 NA 1 2 2 1 "" "REINGRESO: ASISTE POR EMPEORAMIENTO DE LOS SÍNTOMAS"', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=" ", quote="\"")
```

Comment: Gracias patricio tengo 56 pacientes y si me dejó solo esas filas y muchas columnas, pero solo me aparece completa una sola fila con la columna del ID pero  las demás vacías.

Comment: ¿Cual de las dos opciones has probado? ¿Cómo has ejecutado estos comandos? ¿Puedes compartir una muestra de los datos que mencionas como texto en tu  pregunta?

Comment: Los dos:  names<-names(df2)
names<-names[-1] #Quito record_id

df2_piv <-df2%>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = record_id, 
              values_from=c(names))  # Este me da error.                                                  Y este: df2_shape<-reshape(df2, timevar = "fyhingresopte", idvar = "record_id", direction = "wide") ->Este me sale solo una fila completa las demás vacias.

Comment: Sin ver los datos reales se me hace dificil ver el problema, ¿en el primer caso que error te da? por otro lado cuantas fechas distintas tienes: `unique(df$fyhingresopte)`?

Comment: "record_id" "fyhingresopte" "pruebacovid" "resultadopcr" "viaje14d" "personalsalud" "contacto14d" "ingresourgencias" "otrainstitucion" "observacionesingresourg"
1 "2020-03-20 23:58" 1 1 2 2 1 2 "" "NINGUNA"
1 "" NA NA NA NA NA NA "" ""
2 "2020-03-29 09:46" 1 1 2 2 2 1 "" "Llevado por su madre"
10 "2020-03-13 22:41" 1 2 1 2 2 1 "" ""
10 "2020-03-16 01:10" 2 NA 1 2 2 1 "" "REINGRESO: ASISTE POR EMPEORAMIENTO DE LOS SÍNTOMAS"

Comment: @nelpin, aún con estos datos, las funciones hacen lo que planteaste en tu pregunta, transforman  todas las variables en columnas en función de la fecha, el tema es que tienes varias fechas (con hora encima) . Por ejemplo para el `record_id = 1` vas a tener una columna `pruebacovid_2020-03-20 23:58` (entre otras)  pero en las otras filas por ejemplo en el `record_id = 10 `no tienes la misma fecha, por lo que obviamente no vas a tener datos en la columna `pruebacovid_2020-03-20 23:58` y así con cada caso. ¿Que es lo que estás esperando que ocurra?

Comment: Gracias @Patricio por su respuesta, lo que necesito es que si hay por ejemplo dos `record_id = 10` Solo me aparezca una fila para este, este caso el df original tiene _10 columnas_ al transformarlo tendría _19 columnas_, lo de las fechas efectivamente muy difícil que se repitan o que coincidan entre registros, no se si me hice entender.

Comment: Si creo que te entiendo, pero el tema no depende del `record_id=10` sino de todo el resto, si tienes una `record_id` que tuviera 10 filas tu `data.frame` final tendrá 91 columnas, verifica el último código que te agregué a mi respuesta.