# Problemas con los nombres de las columnas

Tags: r

Estoy haciendo una extracción de genes con Bioconductor y la librería GeoQuery fundamentalmente, de una base de datos de NCBI, el problema surge cuando hago un **merge** entre dos df,para una de los df debo hacer un **transpose** y cuando cambia el sentido de la tabla, se crea una fila encima de los nombres con valores X1, X2, X3... hasta X50, y los nombres de mis genes quedan debajo, pero no terminan siendo los nombres de mis columnas, me trae problemas porque no he podido corregir ese problema.

Es algo así, mi df de genes y sus datos de expresión

```
     Valores 
Gen1 0.15
Gen2 0.12
Gen3 0.16
Gen4 0.15
```

Luego del *transpose* queda

```
X1  | X2  |  X3 |
Gen1| Gen2| Gen3|
0.15| 0.12|0.16 |
```

Finalmente terminan siendo los nombres de las columnas los X1... X50

y me interrumpe otro proceso.

Les agradezco su ayuda de antemano

Comment: ¡Bienvenido Lussac a SO en español! Si creas un ejemplo reproducible del problema  será mucho más fácil que obtengas una respuesta. Para hacerlo puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar 1) el código que estás usando y con el que se presenta el problema, 2) un ejemplo de datos en los que se presenta el problema y 3)  descripción del resultado esperado.

Comment: En este caso, por lo que veo, el problema es que no están bien separados datos de los metadatos (tienes los nombres de fila en una columna) y entonces la función `t()` hace lo que se espera que haga: poner a cada fila como una columnas (incluyendo la que nombra a los genes), inventarse unos nombres de columna porque no encontró nombres de fila y coercionar a toda la estructura a la clase `character`.  Para trabajar con data.frame esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363484/como-pasar-filas-a-columnas-en-r y su respuesta pueden ayudarte mucho.

Comment: Los datos que aportas no son claros para identificar el problema, el  `df`  que muestras pareciera que tiene los datos de genes como `rowname`, pero entonces no explica por que `t()` funciona mal (tampoco sabemos si estás usando `t()`), ahora si los genes están como columna, tampoco se explica la salida de `t()` ya que no inventa nombres de columnas al devolver una matriz. ¿Por que no agregas a tu pregunta lo que te indicó mpaladino? así evitamos adivinar que puede ser lo que está pasando.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que los nombres de los genes se encuentran en una columna de tu `data.frame` (podrían estar como `row.names()`, y por el enunciado de tu pregunta no queda claro) hay dos posibilidades:

1. Con **R** base: Elimina la columna de los nombres, transpone y
   crea un nuevo `data.frame`, y renombra las columnas con el vector de
   nombres
2. Usando `tidyverse`, en concreto el paquete `tidyr`.

Te pongo un ejemplo con cada una de las alternativas. Saludos:

```r
df_genes <- data.frame(
  nombre = c("Gen1", "Gen2", "Gen3", "Gen4"),
  Valores = c(.15, .12, .16, .15)
)

# Replicando el punto de partida
t(as.matrix(df_genes))
#>         [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]  
#> nombre  "Gen1" "Gen2" "Gen3" "Gen4"
#> Valores "0.15" "0.12" "0.16" "0.15"

df_genes[, "Valores"]
#> [1] 0.15 0.12 0.16 0.15

# Con base R
# Crea el df eliminando la columna con nombres ()
new_df <- as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(df_genes[, "Valores"])))
colnames(new_df) <- df_genes$nombre

new_df
#>   Gen1 Gen2 Gen3 Gen4
#> 1 0.15 0.12 0.16 0.15


# Tidyverse approach
library(tidyr)

# Usa pivot_wider
df_transp <- df_genes %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = nombre,
    values_from = Valores
  )

df_transp
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>    Gen1  Gen2  Gen3  Gen4
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  0.15  0.12  0.16  0.15
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>